# TYPO3 v9 caching error with site-configuration.php-file?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, ddev

I'm working on a new project in TYPO3. It's my frist installation of TYPO3 9.5.5 so I don't know if this is some sort of bug or anything but sometimes, and I really can't give you any more information about it since I dont know where it comes from and how to reproduce this error, my enire typo3 crashes with this error message:

```
(1/1) #1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception
PHP Warning: rename(/var/www/html/var/cache/code/cache_core/5cab444370d80224649952.temp,/var/www/html/var/cache/code/cache_core/site-configuration.php): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/SimpleFileBackend.php line 234
```

Since it's in my var directory I figured to just delete the entire folder but as soon as I try to delete it Windows tells me I don't have permission to delete this file or even change it. When I try to open it in an editor it tells me that the file doesn't exist and I can't do anything about it unless I restart my entire PC.

I've found some people with the same issue [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87174), but no way to fix it or anything on how to prevent it from happening.

I'm using the composer installation of TYPO3 with ddev on Windows 10.

Does anyone know about this error or can tell me anything on how to fix it?

Comment: Just a note that this *has* bee reported before, and especially on Windows. Are you using Docker Toolbox (usually Win 10 Home) or Docker for Windows (requires Windows 10 Pro)?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I figure that this had to be reported before. Me and a college of mine both had the same issue in different projects independend from each other. I'm using Docker for Windows right now.

Comment: Sometimes I get those messages, after refreshing the frame or page everything is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flush all TYPO3 caches?

To do so, go to Admin Tools => Maintenance => Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache.

If the problem persists, you can try to got to Admin Tools => Environment => Directory Status and check if all permissions are set properly.

And since you run TYPO3 with ddev, you can use the shell (Putty or whatwever) and do a `ddev ssh` to login directly to the container and delete the files there.

Comment: Hi, yes I flushed all the caches, Even deleted typo3temp completly once. The Problem wasn't fixed though. The file just has to be deleted and it will be generated again but I can't delete it normally since Windows doesn't allow me to. I worked around the issue by just restarting my PC in safe mode and deleting the entire var folder and restarting again in normal mode. Really time consuming but it works for now as long as I don't know where the actual problem is.